# Should port 25 be open on localhost (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: nmap

Port 25 is open on localhost and also on my internal `192.168.1.xxx` number. The nmap scan shows:

```
25/tcp open  smtp Postfix smtpd
```

Should this be the case? I am not trying to run an SMTP server. However, for all I know, this is standard for Linux. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

I hope someone can let me know, thanks.

Comment: This depends on your contextual use. Should it be open on local-host for itself? Perhaps not, and you can close the port. If you only want Port 25 traffic to come from outside your local broadcast domain, then it should be *safe* to block it. Just give it a shot and see the adverse effects. I have mine open, but to select hosts.

Comment: Is there an approved way to close it. I could apt purge Postfix but I wonder if that's the best way.